# hypothetical: how would you implement bidirectional language support in Sublime text editor, and what features would you like it to have?

Tags: internationalization, sublimetext3, bidi

Maybe this question is too open-ended and someone will kill it
--- however:

I am building systems (web apps and native) requiring multiple language support, including rtl languages like Arabic and Hebrew.  Currently I have no need to be able to program in those languages, but writing content is a must.

There are some difficult choices to make I think in the implementation, because I think at some level (I don't know it's why I'm asking) the text file needs to have a consistent direction of string flow, but when we read and compose these files we need to view these elements with their character order reversed in order for them to be sensible.

(Open ended and non-constructive?  I'm hoping to construct a solution.)

Comment: http://decodize.com/html/sublime-text-2-bidirectional-language-support-plugin/

Comment: itb i'm going to be using gedit to create files, then fs.readFileSync and underscore.string `reverse` method to write them into objects.
https://github.com/edtsech/underscore.string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see the connection with SublimeText.

You need RTL support, you use a pre-made component that can handle it.
Or start with a library that can help with that support and does the heavy-lifting (for instance Uniscribe, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx,
or HarfBuzz, http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/)

Adding it yourself means a lot of work (SublimeText fails miserably at it, I don't even think it tries).

To get an idea what you have to deal with, take a look at the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm
(http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/)

Comment: yeah i was stretching the boundaries of the acceptable with this question.  so open-ended.  Gedit has good bidi support and some people have done it for ST2, but it's a mess no matter what because to be able to read it the editor has to kind of lie to you about the actual order of the char array for that section.

Comment: I'll look into the links you've provided when I get time.

Comment: Again, for my purposes, to keep things clean, I'll be doing all my RTL content in GEdit, storing it in objects with `fs`, and reversing its order with `underscore.string.reverse`.  Actually seems better than the confusion of putting RTL content into a Jade file.

Comment: You should not reverse the string, that is not how it works. Things should happen at a way lower level, in the text layout engine. Not only the order of rendering change (without reordering the characters in the string), but you also need to read the OpenType tables in the font to choose the right glyphs.

Comment: If you want to learn more, look at HarfBuzz (it is open source), Pango (http://www.pango.org/, also open source), the TR#9 link, Microsoft typography (especially the docs here http://www.microsoft.com/typography/SpecificationsOverview.mspx and here http://www.microsoft.com/typography/Glyph%20Processing/intro.mspx)

Comment: i wasn't going to reverse the string for a text-editor implementation, just for content going into objects going into --well, other objects. jade templates ultimately.
btw, thx for the feedback and links!

Comment: "just for content going into objects going into --well, other objects" There is no need to do that. Ever. If some component asks for that, then the component is broken.

Answer (score 1):

**Just vote for adding RTL Languages here...**

https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/37207-right-to-left-languages-support/

**They will add it if the votes reach 600**